# Codeigniter beginner question

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a codeigniter website what handles youtube videos.

Somet details are stored it the database, id, title, embed, thumbnail, description, duration.

I managed to show the list of videos.

And I would like that if someone clics on the thumbnail, it loads up the video.

Well I didn't had any luck with it.

I'm trying `<a href='video?video_name_here'>thumbnail</a>` then go to the video page and show the video embed.

I don't want anybody to write it for me, i just only would like a more experienced persons help giving me a hint.

Thank you.

Comment: We'll probably need a bit more information to help: what happens when you click the thumbnail? Can you view the video page w/o clicking on the thumbnails? If so, does the URL in the href attribute match the correct URL of the video page? Some code from the video page and thumbnail page would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have videos controller with a play method that takes the video url as an argument. I appreciate you wanna try it so im just givin you a mock up here.

```
Class Videos extends CI_Controller {
  function play($url) {
   embed_play($url);
 }
}
```

In your links in thumbnails do this

```
<?php echo anchor("videos/play/".$video_url,"Video 1"); ?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using Colorbox?

http://trueacu.com/YouTube_Colorbox

you'd have to create your link like this:

```
<a class="example6" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KWRB-maTVyM" title="Xampp Installation">
Xampp Installation Video on YouTube</a>
```

and you should also add this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".example6").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
});
//]]>
</script>
```